# Shared elements in graphviz but need overlapping groups

Tags: graphviz

Trying to document several sub-projects that utilize sql to achieve their final data. This is done in sql scripts and sql macros which make use of tables and views. Should end up with an easily maintainable whole picture of table and view dependencies. With Graphviz so far so good, dependencies concerned. However i can't find any paradigm in graphviz to show the groupings of the sql scripts, macros and sub-projects, with their overlaps of views and tables used. I know that clusters can't overlap in graphviz. Is there any way possible in graphviz that would function to show which views and tables are shared such that the sharing groups are labeled or dotted around etc?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why i didn't think of it earlier. Instead of other paradigms, a node can also represent grouping relationships. Thus, a sub-project can be a node, sql script and macro can also be a node. They connect to the underlying views and tables by edges. The whole groupings can be easily seen, as can the sharing of edges. Peace out.